# Movie where a man is injected with alien DNA that heals his wounds

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember watching this movie around 2008-2010. It's in English and perhaps a typical Hollywood movie. I only remember this part of the movie.

A man and a woman trapped in a room (maybe a storage room) have one injection and must choose who should be injected. Both are wounded, I think. Finally, the man receives the injection and his wounds are healed. The injection contains alien DNA of some sort. They study this alien.

The man is wearing military clothing and has guns. I think the woman was blonde and wore white clothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible this was the 2005 movie *[Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_(film))*; the protagonist, Reaper, is mortally wounded and his sister, a scientist, injects him with the Martian DNA (C24 serum) to save his life.  It heals his wound and makes him a super-soldier capable of taking on the C24-infected, but psychotic, sergeant.

You can see the scientist (Rosamund Pike) and Reaper (Karl Urban) in this scene, although it doesn't show the injection:

Comment: yes this is it. How could I forget about the Dwayne Johnson.

Comment: @Shota Lots of us want to forget that movie...

Comment: The Rock was pure gold in this movie. "I need soldiers! I don't need anybody else, but soldiers!"